# How to remove spacing between rotated elements?

Tags: html, css

The effect I am looking for is this:

[image]

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/q1m42ees/) is what I have at the moment. I think the problem is that the elements are getting positioned and keeping those set positions after being rotated and so not moving closer.

The page layout is a simple list.

```
<body>
<div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">page one</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">page two</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">a longer page three</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">another page</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle.net with what you currently have? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use negative `margin` and move last `li` element to the right like:

```css
#navmenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
#navmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  /* font-size: 0; */
}
#navmenu ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  margin-left: -106px;
}
#navmenu ul a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-property: transform;
}
#navmenu ul a:hover {
  transform: translate(-50px, 0px);
}
#navmenu ul a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#navmenu ul li:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  right: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">page one</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">page two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">a longer page three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">another page</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think in the absence of JS this is probably the best way to go. Like @Gaby my solution (which BTW set the rotation on the UL) involved manually setting each child to have a different margin/left value, and even if you used a pre-compiler to functionalise that it's still slightly messy.

Answer (score 0):

If you read http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-rendering it states

> **Note**: Transformations do affect the **visual rendering**, but have **no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow**.

You have to space them manually (*or with js if the rotations and the element sizes etc are not fixed*)

Example:

```css
#navmenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position:relative;
}

#navmenu ul li {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
#navmenu ul li:nth-child(2){left:60px}
#navmenu ul li:nth-child(3){left:120px}
#navmenu ul li:nth-child(4){left:180px}

#navmenu ul a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;

  display: inline-block;

  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;

  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;

  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-property: transform;     
}    

#navmenu ul a:hover {
  transform:translate(-50px, 0px);
}

#navmenu ul a:active {
  position:relative;
  top:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">page one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a longer page three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">another page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```